# Getting latest update of certificate/credential/SSL store

Tags: certificates

I realize sometimes when browsing with HTTPS, it shows the certificate is not valid, "This certificate is not from a trusted authority". Clicking "continue" will just pop up the same warning. That time, I start thinking the certificate store is not updated. I try to compare with Windows trusted CA which will be updated automatically.

I think the certificate must be updated in a period of time since the validity of trusted CA is about 1 to a few years.

I cannot find this thing mention in Android anywhere. Does the way it manages certificates is different? How can I make sure I get the latest update?

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, this will finally be addressed. Android 14 will update the trust store via Google Play Store. Earlier versions required the device manufacturer to push an over-the-air update with new certificates, which wasn't always provided quickly or at all for older devices.

https://www.xda-developers.com/android-14-root-certificates-updatable/